# Unity 2019.3.3f1 crashes under Mac OSX Catalina and Mojave

Tags: unity-game-engine, macos-mojave, macos-catalina

I'm trying to run a github repo [that can found in here.](https://github.com/denisgriaznov/MyoArmControl) with Unity 2019.3.3f1 . Which works fine on Windows10 but instantly crashes on Mac OS Mojave and Catalina. This is the first time that I've came across a Unity error like this, any ideas would really helpful :))

Error message: [link](https://hastebin.com/uyuwezokuw.js)

Comment: Is it reproducible in an empty project? You could file a bug report to unity. Can you figure out what part of the engine crashes? Have you tried a debug build?

Answer (score 1):

This error persists since Unity 2019.3.0 and is still there in the latest version (2019.3.13). So we are unable to upgrade and have to stick with Unity 2019.2.21. We will consider switching to the Unreal Engine for our next project.